# How to display radio buttons in multiple rows in Android

Tags: android

I need to display 4 RadioButtons of same Radiogroup in 2 rows.

The  firstrow contains 2 Radio Buttons and next row contains 2 Radio Buttons. How can we achieve this in Android using RadioGroup. Can anyone provide sample code for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

RadioGroup extends LinearLayout. Then two rows is impossible, I think.
Create wrapper that wraps group of RadioGroups and implement/delegate checking/unchecking and event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is kinda possible... at least partly!

What you need to do is to create a `RelativeLayout` that will be wraped between your `RadioGroup` and your `RadioButton`s. Then, for each `RadioButton`, give a `RelativeLayout` Rule to select the position, like this:

```
RadioGroup fromRadioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    RelativeLayout fromChoice = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RadioButton fromNow = new RadioButton(this);
        fromNow.setText(R.string.Now);
        fromNow.setId(1000);
    fromChoice.addView(fromNow);
        RadioButton fromTomo = new RadioButton(this);
        fromTomo.setText(R.string.Tomorrow);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1000);
        fromTomo.setLayoutParams(relParams1);
    fromChoice.addView(fromTomo);
        RadioButton fromNextW = new RadioButton(this);
        fromNextW.setText(R.string.NextWeek);
        fromNextW.setId(100100);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1000);
        fromNextW.setLayoutParams(relParams2);
    fromChoice.addView(fromNextW);
        RadioButton fromNextM = new RadioButton(this);
        fromNextM.setText(R.string.NextMonth);
        fromNextM.setId(100200);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1000);
        relParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 100100);
        fromNextM.setLayoutParams(relParams3);
    fromChoice.addView(fromNextM);
fromRadioGroup.addView(fromChoice);
```

Now, the `RadioButton`s are displaying on two lines, but they don't react as part of the same `RadioGroup` anymore... basically, I can select more than one radio from the same group, and when looking at what `fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns, (-1), it's clearly not considering any `RadioButton` as child... witch brings us to the point of nearly useless solution. Or maybe there is a way to force the childs back to their `RadioGroup` but I havn't found any yet.
Cheers.